# Build FFMPEG for Android error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I cannot build FFMPEG for Android in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits. I have followed many tutorials but still cannot do it right. I'm using the project recommended by FFMPEG team: https://github.com/cine-io/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp.

But I get this error in the terminal when I run build.sh:

```
douglas@douglas-mob:~/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp$ ./build.sh
Setting up build environment ...
Looking for the NDK ...
find: `/usr/share/doc/google-chrome-stable': Permissão negada
Path to NDK []: /home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9
Saving configuration into /home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/.build-config.sh ...
OS_ARCH=linux-x86_64
NDK=/home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9
SYSROOT=/home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
TOOLCHAIN=/home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
Building openssl-android ...
Building librtmp for android ...
Couldn't build librtmp for android!
Check the build log: /home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/build/build.log
```

And the build.log file content is as follows:

> Cloning into
>   '/home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android'...
>   Android NDK:
>   WARNING:/home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android/crypto/Android.mk:crypto_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries     Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= cryptlib.c
>   /home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android/crypto/cryptlib.c:
>   In function 'CRYPTO_THREADID_current':
>   /home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android/crypto/cryptlib.c:503:2:
>   warning: passing argument 2 of 'CRYPTO_THREADID_set_pointer' discards
>   'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
>   /home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android/crypto/cryptlib.c:431:6:
>   note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int volatile *'
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= mem.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= mem_clr.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= mem_dbg.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   cversion.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ex_data.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= cpt_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ebcdic.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= uid.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= o_time.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= o_str.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= o_dir.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= aes_cbc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= aes_cfb.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= aes_ctr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= aes_ecb.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= aes_misc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= aes_ofb.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= aes_wrap.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   a_bitstr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_bool.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= a_bytes.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_d2i_fp.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= a_digest.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_dup.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= a_enum.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_gentm.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= a_i2d_fp.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_int.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_mbstr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   a_object.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_octet.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= a_print.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_set.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= a_sign.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_strex.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= a_strnid.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_time.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_type.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   a_utctm.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= a_utf8.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= a_verify.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ameth_lib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= asn1_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= asn1_gen.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= asn1_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= asn1_par.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= asn_mime.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   asn_moid.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= asn_pack.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= bio_asn1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bio_ndef.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= d2i_pr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= d2i_pu.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= evp_asn1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   f_enum.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= f_int.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   f_string.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= i2d_pr.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= i2d_pu.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= n_pkey.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= nsseq.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p5_pbe.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= p5_pbev2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p8_pkey.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= t_bitst.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= t_crl.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= t_pkey.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= t_req.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= t_spki.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   t_x509.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= t_x509a.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= tasn_dec.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= tasn_enc.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= tasn_fre.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= tasn_new.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= tasn_prn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= tasn_typ.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= tasn_utl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   x_algor.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_attrib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= x_bignum.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_crl.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= x_exten.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_info.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= x_long.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_name.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_nx509.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   x_pkey.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_pubkey.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= x_req.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_sig.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= x_spki.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_val.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= x_x509.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x_x509a.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= bf_cfb64.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bf_ecb.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= bf_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bf_ofb64.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= bf_skey.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= b_dump.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= b_print.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   b_sock.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bf_buff.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= bf_nbio.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bf_null.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= bio_cb.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bio_err.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= bio_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bss_acpt.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= bss_bio.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bss_conn.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= bss_dgram.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   bss_fd.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bss_file.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= bss_log.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bss_mem.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= bss_null.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bss_sock.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= bn_add.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_asm.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_blind.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   bn_ctx.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_div.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= bn_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_exp.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= bn_exp2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_gcd.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= bn_gf2m.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_kron.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= bn_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_mod.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_mont.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   bn_mpi.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_mul.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= bn_nist.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_prime.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= bn_print.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_rand.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= bn_recp.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_shift.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_sqr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   bn_sqrt.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bn_word.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= buf_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= buffer.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= c_rle.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= c_zlib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= comp_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= comp_lib.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= conf_api.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= conf_def.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= conf_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   conf_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= conf_mall.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= conf_mod.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= conf_sap.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= cbc_cksm.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= cbc_enc.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= cfb64ede.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   cfb64enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= cfb_enc.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= des_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= des_old.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= des_old2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecb3_enc.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= ecb_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ede_cbcm_enc.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= enc_read.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   enc_writ.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= fcrypt.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= fcrypt_b.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ofb64ede.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= ofb64enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ofb_enc.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= pcbc_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= qud_cksm.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= rand_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   read2pwd.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rpc_enc.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= set_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= str2key.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= xcbc_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dh_ameth.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= dh_asn1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dh_check.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= dh_depr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   dh_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dh_gen.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= dh_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dh_lib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= dh_pmeth.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_ameth.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= dsa_asn1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_depr.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   dsa_gen.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= dsa_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_ossl.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= dsa_pmeth.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_prn.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= dsa_sign.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dsa_vrf.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_dl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   dso_dlfcn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_err.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= dso_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_null.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= dso_openssl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_vms.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= dso_win32.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   ec2_mult.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec2_smpl.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= ec_ameth.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec_asn1.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= ec_check.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec_curve.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec_cvt.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   ec_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= ec_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec_mult.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= ec_pmeth.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ec_print.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= eck_prn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecp_mont.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecp_nist.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   ecp_smpl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ech_err.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= ech_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ech_lib.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= ech_ossl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecs_asn1.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= ecs_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecs_lib.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecs_ossl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   ecs_sign.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ecs_vrf.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= err_all.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= err_prn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bio_b64.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= bio_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= bio_md.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= bio_ok.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= c_all.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= c_allc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= c_alld.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= digest.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_aes.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_bf.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_des.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_des3.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   e_null.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_old.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   e_rc2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_rc4.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   e_rc5.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= e_xcbc_d.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= encode.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= evp_acnf.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= evp_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= evp_err.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= evp_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= evp_lib.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= evp_pbe.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= evp_pkey.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_dss.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_dss1.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_ecdsa.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   m_md4.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_md5.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   m_mdc2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_null.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= m_ripemd.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_sha1.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= m_sigver.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= m_wp.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= names.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p5_crpt.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= p5_crpt2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p_dec.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= p_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p_lib.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= p_open.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p_seal.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= p_sign.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   p_verify.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pmeth_fn.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= pmeth_gn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pmeth_lib.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= hm_ameth.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= hm_pmeth.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= hmac.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   krb5_asn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= lh_stats.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= lhash.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= md4_dgst.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= md4_one.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= md5_dgst.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= md5_one.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= cbc128.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= cfb128.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   ctr128.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ofb128.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= o_names.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= obj_dat.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= obj_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= obj_lib.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= obj_xref.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_asn.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_cl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_err.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_ext.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   ocsp_ht.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_lib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= ocsp_prn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_srv.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= ocsp_vfy.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_all.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   pem_info.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_lib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= pem_oth.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_pk8.c Compile thumb
>   : crypto <= pem_pkey.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_seal.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= pem_sign.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_x509.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= pem_xaux.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   pvkfmt.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_add.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= p12_asn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_attr.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= p12_crpt.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_crt.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= p12_decr.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_init.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_key.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   p12_kiss.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_mutl.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= p12_npas.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_p8d.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= p12_p8e.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= p12_utl.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= pk12err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   pk7_asn1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pk7_attr.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= pk7_doit.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pk7_lib.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= pk7_mime.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pk7_smime.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= pkcs7err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   md_rand.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rand_egd.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= rand_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rand_lib.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= rand_unix.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= randfile.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= rc2_cbc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   rc2_ecb.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rc2_skey.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= rc2cfb64.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rc2ofb64.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= rc4_enc.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rc4_skey.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= rmd_dgst.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   rmd_one.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_ameth.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= rsa_asn1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_chk.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= rsa_eay.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_err.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_gen.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   rsa_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_none.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= rsa_null.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_oaep.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= rsa_pk1.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_pmeth.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_prn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   rsa_pss.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_saos.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= rsa_sign.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= rsa_ssl.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= rsa_x931.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= sha1_one.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= sha1dgst.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   sha256.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= sha512.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= sha_dgst.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= stack.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= ts_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= txt_db.c Compile thumb 
>   : crypto <= ui_compat.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ui_err.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= ui_lib.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= ui_openssl.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= ui_util.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   by_dir.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= by_file.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= x509_att.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_cmp.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= x509_d2.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_def.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= x509_err.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_ext.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_lu.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   x509_obj.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_r2x.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= x509_req.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_set.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= x509_trs.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_txt.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_v3.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   x509_vfy.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509_vpm.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= x509cset.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509name.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= x509rset.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509spki.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= x509type.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   x_all.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pcy_cache.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= pcy_data.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pcy_lib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= pcy_map.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= pcy_node.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= pcy_tree.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_akey.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_akeya.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   v3_alt.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_bcons.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= v3_bitst.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_conf.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= v3_cpols.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_crld.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= v3_enum.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_extku.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_genn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   v3_ia5.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_info.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= v3_int.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_lib.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= v3_ncons.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_ocsp.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= v3_pci.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_pcia.c
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_pcons.c Compile thumb  : crypto <=
>   v3_pku.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_pmaps.c Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= v3_prn.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_purp.c Compile thumb  :
>   crypto <= v3_skey.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3_sxnet.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= v3_utl.c Compile thumb  : crypto <= v3err.c Compile
>   thumb  : crypto <= aes-armv4.S Compile thumb  : crypto <= armv4-mont.S
>   Compile thumb  : crypto <= sha1-armv4-large.S Compile thumb  : crypto
>   <= sha256-armv4.S Compile thumb  : crypto <= sha512-armv4.S
>   SharedLibrary  : libcrypto.so Install        : libcrypto.so =>
>   libs/armeabi/libcrypto.so Compile thumb  : openssl <= app_rand.c
>   Compile thumb  : openssl <= apps.c Compile thumb  : openssl <=
>   asn1pars.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= ca.c Compile thumb  : openssl
>   <= ciphers.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= crl.c Compile thumb  :
>   openssl <= crl2p7.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= dgst.c Compile thumb 
>   : openssl <= dh.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= dhparam.c Compile thumb 
>   : openssl <= dsa.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= dsaparam.c Compile
>   thumb  : openssl <= ecparam.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= ec.c Compile
>   thumb  : openssl <= enc.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= engine.c Compile
>   thumb  : openssl <= errstr.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= gendh.c
>   Compile thumb  : openssl <= gendsa.c Compile thumb  : openssl <=
>   genpkey.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= genrsa.c Compile thumb  :
>   openssl <= nseq.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= ocsp.c Compile thumb  :
>   openssl <= openssl.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= passwd.c Compile
>   thumb  : openssl <= pkcs12.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= pkcs7.c
>   Compile thumb  : openssl <= pkcs8.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= pkey.c
>   Compile thumb  : openssl <= pkeyparam.c Compile thumb  : openssl <=
>   pkeyutl.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= prime.c Compile thumb  : openssl
>   <= rand.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= req.c Compile thumb  : openssl
>   <= rsa.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= rsautl.c Compile thumb  : openssl
>   <= s_cb.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= s_client.c Compile thumb  :
>   openssl <= s_server.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= s_socket.c Compile
>   thumb  : openssl <= s_time.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= sess_id.c
>   Compile thumb  : openssl <= smime.c Compile thumb  : openssl <=
>   speed.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= spkac.c Compile thumb  : openssl
>   <= verify.c Compile thumb  : openssl <= version.c Compile thumb  :
>   openssl <= x509.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s2_meth.c Compile thumb  :
>   ssl <= s2_srvr.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s2_clnt.c Compile thumb  :
>   ssl <= s2_lib.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s2_enc.c Compile thumb  : ssl
>   <= s2_pkt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s3_meth.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   s3_srvr.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s3_clnt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   s3_lib.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s3_enc.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   s3_pkt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s3_both.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   s23_meth.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s23_srvr.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   s23_clnt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= s23_lib.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   s23_pkt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= t1_meth.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   t1_srvr.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= t1_clnt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   t1_lib.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= t1_enc.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   t1_reneg.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= ssl_lib.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   ssl_err2.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= ssl_cert.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   ssl_sess.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= ssl_ciph.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   ssl_stat.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= ssl_rsa.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   ssl_asn1.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= ssl_txt.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   ssl_algs.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= bio_ssl.c Compile thumb  : ssl <=
>   ssl_err.c Compile thumb  : ssl <= kssl.c SharedLibrary  : libssl.so
>   Executable     : openssl Install        : openssl =>
>   libs/armeabi/openssl Install        : libssl.so =>
>   libs/armeabi/libssl.so Compile thumb  : ssltest <= ssltest.c
>   Executable     : ssltest Install        : ssltest =>
>   libs/armeabi/ssltest Cloning into
>   '/home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/rtmpdump'... patching
>   file Makefile
>   /home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   -Wall -marm -I/home/douglas/dev/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/src/openssl-android/include
>   -isysroot /home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
>   -I/home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -DRTMPDUMP_VERSION=\"v2.4\" -DUSE_OPENSSL   -fPIC   -c -o rtmp.o rtmp.c In file included from rtmp.c:26:0:
>   /home/douglas/dev/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/include/stdint.h:9:26:
>   fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory  # include_next
>   
>                             ^ compilation terminated. : recipe for target 'rtmp.o' failed make: *** [rtmp.o] Error 1

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: When the source git project says 'tested with NDK-r10' and your path says 'android-ndk-r9' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Morrison Chang answered, the error was on typing "android-ndk-r9" when prompted.

The correct is to type "android-ndk-r10e".

Comment: Also I had to do was install libssl-dev using the command:

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev